# How to use sqlite database on ubuntu server

Tags: c#, sqlite, ubuntu, entity-framework-core

I wanted to use sqlite on my server for my asp.net core application, but I'm having trouble undestanding how to communicate with it. There is no information about how to create a connection string for it, and I saw comments that it is not a server/client database type, but I see comments where people say they use sqlite on their servers, so my question is how do they do it?

I want to work on my project and build my database structure with code-first approach locally, push changes to the server and let the database work on the server. I added sqlite to my entity framework in the project with:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<TetrominoContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection")));
```

But I don't know how to build the connection string.

If I were to create a db file on the ubuntu server then how do I specify path to that file in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Connection strings in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite look like this:

```
Filename=/path/to/my.db
```